# Does model of MVP belongs to presentation layer or domain layer?

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp

I understand the MVP. However i do not understand model belongs to presentation layer or domain layer. It is said in some resources, mvp only models the presentation layer, in other words model is in presentation layer. https://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

However, in other resources https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29 , model belongs to domain layer. Which one is correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different types of models. You can have a [DomainModel](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html), a [PresentationModel](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) an ApplicationModel etc.

You can use each kind of model in an MVP application if you need to. for example if you have a complex application with multiple ***Presenters*** that need to communicate with each other it may be usefull to add an additional ***ApplicationModel*** to simplify these communications by adding a ***Model*** that has ***Application specific data and behavior***. If you don't have that you can just use a pure ***DomainModel***.

In [this article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html), Martin Fowler says:

> Supervising Controller decomposes presentation functionality into two
>   parts: a controller (often called presenter) and view. The domain data
>   that needs to be displayed is separate, and following rough MVC
>   terminology I'll refer to it as a model, although it need not be a
>   Domain Model.

It's a tricky one, but the basic distintion is that a pure ***DomainModel*** usually models some domain (math, banking etc.) and has no presentation or application specific data and/or behavior. You can mix different types of models in your application.

If your application has some complex logic, say that when one thing is selected another thing need to be deselected. you can capture this in a specific Model let's say `ApplicationState` that is not a ***DomainModel***.

Here's an example. Let's say that we have an application that has ***Keywords*** and ***Tags*** and displays them to the user. The user can select only a ***Keyword*** or a ***Tag***. He can't select both at the same time. Here's a way to do this by sing a Model that captures this application specific logic that is not part of our ***Domain***. We are using the observer pattern here. When this ***Model*** changes we raise events.

```
class ApplicationSate : Subject {

    private Tag mSelectedTag;
    private Keyword mSelectedKeyword;

    public Tag getSelectedTag() { return mSelectedTag;  }
    public Keyword getSelectedKeyword() { return mSelectedKeyword; }

    public Tag HasSelectedTag() { return mSelectedTag != null; }
    public Tag HasSelectedKeyword() { return mSelectedKeyword != null; }

    public void selectKeyword(Keyword keyword) {

        if(hasSelectedTag()) {
            mSelectedTag = null;
        }

        mSelectedKeyword = keyword;
        raiseChangedEvent();
    }

    public void selectTag(Tag tag) {

        if(hasSelectedKeyword()){
            mSelectedKeyword = null;
        }

        mSelectedTag = tag;
        raiseChangedEvent();
    }
}
```

Here is a good [article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) on GUI architectures.